# Do python ctypes differ from c++ when dealing with winapi?

Tags: c++, ctypes

I prefer a dynamic language like python as it has easier syntax than
strongly typed languages like c++

I will be writing code that extensively uses win32 api
and my question is whether ctypes differ from c++ when calling winapi in terms of performance and execution speed.

Comment: Ctypes **does** differ from C++, because `ctypes` is a library, and C++ is a programming language.

Comment: I didn't know you can use the WinAPI with Python. :)

Comment: I know ctypes differ from C++, I meant when using them to deal with winapi Is there is any difference in performance?

Comment: @Rapptz : search about ctypes

Comment: @K7rim: The different won't be that big. If you only need a few functions from win32 api or win32 api is not needed for a core functionally, you don't need to use C/C++. In general, in desktop applications where only one user uses the application, the performance is not a big issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure Python code is not as fast as C++.  If you are planning on extensively using the Win32 API, converting from Python types to C types and back again frequently is expensive compared to using C++ with the Win32 API directly.

You should also look into [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/), a library that exposes most of the Win32 API to Python. As @eryksun mentions in the comments below, using straight ctypes means having to write wrappers for C functions, definitions for structures, and context managers for resources, which is prone to error.  Pywin32 alleviates that for the commonly used Win32 APIs, but it doesn't contain them all.

Comment: @eryksun, of course it does, but if the OP still wants to go that route it is easier than writing all the ctypes wrappers, and they have already been modified to have a more pythonic interface, such as wrapping raw Win32 handles in a PyHandle object that will close them when they go out of scope.